# Spring 3.0 (form:select, form:option(s) ) tag library supports HTML 5 data-* attributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Spring 3.0 (form:select, form:option(s) ) tag library supports rendering HTML 5 data-* attributes using a bean's property? If yes , an example would help.
Background : I am developing a Spring MVC app and using Bootstarp css and JS and spring provided tags. Need to use HTML 5 data-* attributes to  keep additional data with dropdowns options. Based upon the user selection in one of the dropdown , I want update further dropdowns and I want to avoid AJAX calls  to fetch  options for next dropdown since I have the data during page load.
I understand JQuery has attribute support but that would require javascript code execution on page load, so looking for HTML 5 support. Any other suggestions to handle this are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data-* attributes are supported on Spring 3.0 form tags (along with any validly-named custom attribute you specify, I believe). You can also use the value of a bean's property as the attribute value, e.g.

```
<form:input data-test="${myBean.propertyName}" path="propertyName" />
```

To answer the second part of your question, where you ask if there's a way to get the Spring form tag library to populate the data-* attributes with the contents of the bean's property that you specify, this does not happen automatically: you would need to write a custom tag that does this.

Comment: How do I handle this with options tag : <form:options items="${countryList}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="nationality" data-test="???" />   . I need ??? to be a property of the bean under countryList list.

Comment: You have to do your own loop. <c:forEach><c:choose><c:when>...etc